# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "colectivos" y "metrobuses" en Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, argentina, diferencias-entre-palabras, transporte

¿Hay una diferencia entre los colectivos y metrobuses en Buenos Aires? Sitios diferentes a veces usan la palabra "colectivo" y otros parecen distinguir entre las palabras. Pero pienso que un *colectivo* es un autobús como un *metrobús*.

Comment: El diccionario de americanismos dice que el [colectivo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=colectivo) es un autobús, y define el [metrobús](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=metrob%C3%BAs) como un autobús en todos los casos (Autobús urbano conectado con el servicio de metro / que suple las rutas no cubiertas por el metro y lleva a los pasajeros a diferentes estaciones). Pero evidentemente esta es una pregunta para nuestros compañeros de La Argentina.

Comment: Aunque es un detalle, cabe agregar que hay metrobuses en la provincia (no ciudad) de Buenos Aires y también en otras tres ciudades: Santa Fe, Neuquén y uno pequeño en Rosario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Argentina son tecnológicamente iguales, sólo diferentes en la circulación —preconfigurada especialmente en una [red de carriles urbanos para el caso de los metrobuses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrob%C3%BAs_(Buenos_Aires)).

> **Colectivo** es la denominación (porteña o mayormente rioplatense*) del **autobús**.

En la ciudad de Buenos Aires

> ***Metrobús*** es un colectivo (o bus) convencional dispuesto para poder circular *[por un carril único cuyas estaciones se ubican en el medio de la avenida](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/sociedad/como-el-metrobus-modifico-el-pulso-de-la-ciudad-nid2041697)*.

(*) En el norte del país, la denominación del bus es ***ómnibus***.